# change data.frame() behavior

Tags: r, dataframe

```
# example data
df <- structure(c(-1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 2), .Dim = 2:3)

# how it looks like
df

r$> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1    0   -1
[2,]    0   -1    2

# construct a data.frame using two rows of df
data.frame(df[1:2, ])

r$> data.frame(df[1:2,])
  X1 X2 X3
1 -1  0 -1
2  0 -1  2

# construct a data.frame using only one row of df
data.frame(df[1, ])

r$> data.frame(df[1, ])
  df.1...
1      -1
2       0
3      -1
```

`data.frame(df[1:2,])` has the same structure as `df`, but `data.frame(df[1, ])` has not.

Is it possible to let `data.frame(df[1, ])` create a data frame with only one row, but not one column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us call the input `m` instead of `df` because it is a matrix and not a data.frame. The two solutions below have the property that they work for both a one row input and a multirow input.  They do not require different code for the two cases.

**1) drop=FALSE** When indexing a matrix there is an optional `drop=` argument which defaults to TRUE which means that the result of a scalar index will be to drop the dimensions and so convert the result to an ordinary vector.  drop has no effect if the index has length > 1.  In that case we always get a matrix.   Stated in another way by default or if drop = TRUE then we get a vector if the index is scalar and a matrix otherwise.  If drop = FALSE then we always get a matrix result.  Thus, specify that drop=FALSE.

```
m <- structure(c(-1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 2), .Dim = 2:3)

m[1, ] # vector
## [1] -1  0 -1

m[1,, drop = TRUE] # same
## [1] -1  0 -1

m[1,, drop = FALSE] # matrix
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   -1    0   -1

m[1:2,, drop = FALSE] # matrix
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   -1    0   -1
## [2,]    0   -1    2
```

Now when we apply data.frame we get a single row.

```
data.frame( m[1,, drop = FALSE] )
##   X1 X2 X3
## 1 -1  0 -1

data.frame(m[1:2,, drop = FALSE])
##   X1 X2 X3
## 1 -1  0 -1
## 2  0 -1  2
```

**2) rbind** If we already have a vector so that it is too late to use drop = FALSE then we can use rbind to ensure that the input is a matrix.

```
data.frame(rbind(m[1, ]))
##   X1 X2 X3
## 1 -1  0 -1

data.frame(rbind(m[1:2, ]))
##   X1 X2 X3
## 1 -1  0 -1
## 2  0 -1  2
```

Comment: `drop = FALSE` is the best solution in my case because it won't break my current code

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
df <- structure(c(-1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 2), .Dim = 2:3)

data.frame(t(df[1, ]))

#>   X1 X2 X3
#> 1 -1  0 -1
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that selecting just one row from a matrix returns a vector, not a matrix:

```r
str(df[1:2, ])
#>  num [1:2, 1:3] -1 0 0 -1 -1 2
str(df[1, ])
#>  num [1:3] -1 0 -1
```

You would have to turn it into a matrix again, to get your expected behavior:

```r
df[1, ] |> 
  matrix(nrow = 1) |> 
  data.frame()
#>   X1 X2 X3
#> 1 -1  0 -1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>